# Why "Settings->Permalinks" creates .htaccess file on nginx server?

Tags: htaccess, nginx

I created a wordpress site and hosted on nginx server, and `settings-> Permalinks` and clicked `save changes`. This creates a .htaccess file on the site root.

On Apache server it's logical and worth creating an .htaccess file, but what it has to do with nginx server?? Is it safe to delete the .htaccess file from the root of my website??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WordPress tries to detect the webserver's type by peeking into the global `$_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE']` variable.

The *Apache* check is:

```
$is_apache = (strpos($_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE'], 'Apache') !== false 
    || strpos($_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE'], 'LiteSpeed') !== false);
```

and the *Nginx* check is:

```
$is_nginx = (strpos($_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE'], 'nginx') !== false);
```

You should therefore first check out:

```
var_dump( $_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE'] );
```

to see if it's correct.

**Here are some alternative workarounds:**

It's also possible to avoid the `.htaccess` file being created with:

```
add_filter( 'flush_rewrite_rules_hard', '__return_false' );
```

to avoid the `save_mod_rewrite_rules()` to run.

Within the `save_mod_rewrite_rules()` function, there's a `got_mod_rewrite()` check before the `.htaccess` is updated. It's also possible to use:

```
add_filter( 'got_rewrite', '__return_false' );
```

to avoid `insert_with_markers()` to run that writes the `.htaccess` file.